# How do I evaluate the equivalent resistance between K and M?

Tags: resistance

[image]

The equivalent resistance between K and L is given 3Ω. How do I evaluate the equivalent resistance between K and M?

I couldn't think of anything so far. Could I get your dear assistance?

Comment: What does your diagram mean? You need to add a lot more information.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's a circle. The question didn't state more info regarding the diagram.

Comment: This is homework so we won't give you a direct answer but help you along. There are two resistance paths between K and L. They are in parallel. (1) What are their ratios? (2) What is the equivalent single resistance between K and L?

Comment: @Transistor Their ratio should be 6:6 = 1:1 so that it will outcome 3 ohm. And how did you get they are in parallel?

Comment: How did you calculate those ratios? There are two paths between K & L. (1) How many degrees circumference is the short one? (2) How many degrees is the long one? (3) Electrically they are parallel resistances as they are two paths between two nodes, K and L.

Comment: You integrate the conductivity of the material or measure it directly, You did not provide a function of the conductivity

Comment: @lap: It's not clear to whom the comment is addressed. I don't think there's any need for integration or discussion of conductivity. How would this help?

Comment: @trans this looks like its straight out of a EM theory book where you are integrating as a function of some function, even if you aren't you still need to know the conductivity. They usually pose these problems over a circle to make you integrate from 0 to pi or whatever the limits of integration are to give you experience with integration over surfaces.

Comment: @laptop2d that is not needed. It is clear from the image that the longer path from K to L is exactly 3 x the shorter path from K to L. Given that the parallel total resistance of those two paths is 3 ohms, it is straightforward to set up parallel resistance equation for long & short paths = 3 ohms, then solve for short path from K to L (by itself). Then you can use that to calculate the resistance from K to M (using parallel resistance equation) if you treat the paths as being multiples of the short K-to-L path.

Comment: @mith yes but the shading suggest to me that the conductivity may be variable along the path length. All I'm saying is I need to know what the function is, if it's flat, then thats fine, I just want to be sure

Comment: "It's a circle" is not helpful. Is the resistance on the **perimeter** or across the **area**? Is the material homogeneous or does the shading have significance?

Comment: Guys, I think given the nature of the question that we can assume the simplest model possible - a circular conductor of uniform resistance per unit length. I think the OP is clearly having trouble solving that and doesn't need further complications.

Answer (score 1):

We here are creatures of circuits.
So some geometric figure like this immediately gets translated into a circuit of R. Since this is divided into quadrants, it makes sense to use a circuit of four  equal-value resistors. I have shown the composite resistance of one of the quadrants in red. Do not make the mistake of thinking R1 = 3 ohms. R1 (as well as R2, R3, R4) must be larger than 3 ohms:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojAot.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Schematics usually avoid angled components, so I have redrawn the four equal-value resistors as you would see them on a schematic drawing (R5,R6,R7,R8). Same circuit.

Comment: I didn't get it properly.

Comment: When you're measuring R1 (K-L) in your diagram, you're actually measuring R1 in parallel with (R2 + R3 + R4). So you know that R1 || (R2 + R3 + R4) == 3ohms. You also know that R1 == R2 == R3 == R4. With this information you can work out what value this is, and then calculate for your K-M.